# Import and export data as files using Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, import, export

I need to be able to export and import data from one instance of my application (spring / hibernate) to another.

My data are stored in multiple tables (with foreign key contraints), and can contain LOBs. I am also required to export the data in files (no specific format).

The [Data pump API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/dp_api.htm)  looks promising but I need to do something "easy to use" (basically a "export those data" button and nothing else), so I can't use external tools such as the one integrated in sql developer

Does spring provide a way to to use this API (or a similar one), or is there another framework that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Spring Data and Batch projects.  They might help.

I don't know what "from one instance to another" means.  Are these separate versions?

Answer (score 0):

if export/import is between database then writing procedures sounds good to me.If it can be for any format(file/webservice) to any then go for mule(http://www.mulesoft.org/what-mule-esb) ,Spring batch.